# Append value to where condition using node with Sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

How to append value to Sequelize where variable

```
let where = {

    [Sequelize.Op.or]:[
        {
            category: {
                [Sequelize.Op.like]: '%some text%'
            }
        },
        {
            category: {
                [Sequelize.Op.like]: '%another text%'
            }
        }
    ]

}
```

I would like to add a new condition to this Sequelize.Op.or

I tried the following code without success:

```
where.[Sequelize.Op.or].push({ color: 'blue' } )
```

and

```
where[[Sequelize.Op.or]].push({ color: 'blue' } )
```

end

```
const or = [Sequelize.Op.or]
where[or].push({ color: 'blue' }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first syntax that you've tried is very close, you should just delete the dot after the `where` :

```
where[Sequelize.Op.or].push({ color: 'blue' } )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
where[Sequelize.Op.or].push({ color: 'blue' })
```